# How to delete a connector in enterprise architect diagram through c# addin

Tags: c#, add-in, enterprise, enterprise-architect, connector

I am using a specific association connector C to connect to a source `element A` and `target element B` in `Enterprise Architect`.

If the user uses this connector between different source and destination elements I want to display an alert message and delete the connector using a `c#` add-in code:

Following is the code I use. I am unable to delete the connector.

```
public void ToDeleteConnectorByID(int connectorID)
        {
            try
            {

                EA.Connector addedConnector = Session.Repository.GetConnectorByID(Convert.ToInt32(connectorID));
                 EA.Element cuurentobjectconnectorele = Session.Repository.GetElementByID(addedConnector.ClientID);

                        for (short m = 0; m < cuurentobjectconnectorele.Connectors.Count - 1; m++)
                        {
                            cuurentobjectconnectorele.Connectors.Delete(m);
                            cuurentobjectconnectorele.Update();
                        }

                    }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("no connector deleted-exception");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below method can be used for adding a connector between elements based on a condition.  It will be triggered when a user drags a new connector from the Toolbox or Resources window, onto a diagram. The notification is provided immediately before the connector is created, so that the Add-In can disable addition of the connector.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// EA_OnPreNewConnector notifies Add-Ins that a new connector is about to be created on a diagram. 
    /// It enables Add-Ins to permit or deny creation of a new connector.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Repository"></param>
    /// <param name="Info"></param>
    /// <returns>Return True to enable addition of the new connector to the model. Return False to disable addition of the new connector.</returns>

public bool EA_OnPreNewConnector(EA.Repository Repository, EA.EventProperties Info)
{
    try
    {
            //To get added Connector Type
            string connectorType = "";
            EA.EventProperty connectorTypePropID;
            connectorTypePropID = Info.Get(0);
            connectorType = connectorTypePropID.Value;

            //To get added Connector stereotype
            string connectorStereotype = "";
            EA.EventProperty connectorStereotypePropID;
            connectorStereotypePropID = Info.Get(2);
            connectorStereotype = connectorStereotypePropID.Value;

            //To get added Connector client ID
            int clientID = 0;
            EA.EventProperty clientIDPropID;
            clientIDPropID = Info.Get(3);
            clientID = Convert.ToInt32(clientIDPropID.Value);

            //To get added Connector Supplier ID
            int supplierID = 0;
            EA.EventProperty supplierIDPropID;
            supplierIDPropID = Info.Get(4);
            supplierID = Convert.ToInt32(supplierIDPropID.Value);

            //To get added Connector diagram
            int diagramID = 0;
            EA.EventProperty diagramIDPropID;
            diagramIDPropID = Info.Get(5);
            diagramID = Convert.ToInt32(diagramIDPropID.Value);

            EA.Element sourceElemnet = Session.Repository.GetElementByID(clientID);
            EA.Element destinationElemnet = Session.Repository.GetElementByID(supplierID);

            if (sourceElemnet != null && destinationElemnet != null)
            {
               //Your condition based on when the connector needs to be created.



                return true;
            }

           MessageBox.Show("This connection is not possible.");
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This connection is not possible.");
           return false;
        }
    }
```

> Returninbg TRUE ,connector will be created.
>   Returning FALSE ,Connector won't be created

Hope it will help you to delete a connector while creating itself.

Comment: @rashmi If it solved , please accept it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of code:

```
public void ToDeleteConnectorByID(int connectorID) {
  try {
    EA.Connector addedConnector = Session.Repository.GetConnectorByID(Convert.ToInt32(connectorID));
    EA.Element currentobjectconnectorele = Session.Repository.GetElementByID(addedConnector.ClientID);

    for (short m = 0; m < currentobjectconnectorele.Connectors.Count; m++) {
      if (addConnector.ConnectorID == currentobjectconnectorele.ConnectorID) {
        currentobjectconnectorele.Connectors.Delete(m);
      }
    }
  }

  catch (Exception ex) {
    MessageBox.Show("no connector deleted-exception");
  }
}
```

Your `Update` is just superfluous and you are deleting all connectors, not just the one you are looking for. Plus your loop is one too short.

N.B: I don't know C# but inside the `if` you could leave the loop. I'd guess that `break` is the keyword.

Comment: I tried this code..still the connector is not getting deleted automatically

Comment: Check, whether the connectorID is correct: print and use the SQL window to locate it: `SELECT * FROM t_connector WHERE connector_id=<theId>`